# how to extract specific data from json and put in to csv using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have  a JSON  which is in nested form. I would like to extract specific data from json and put into csv using pandas python.

```
data = { 
    "class":"hudson.model.Hudson",
    "jobs":[ 
        { 
            "_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
            "name":"git_checkout",
            "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/git_checkout/",
            "builds":[ 
                { 
                    "_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
                    "duration":1201,
                    "number":6,
                    "result":"FAILURE",
                    "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/git_checkout/6/"
                }
            ]
        },
        { 
            "_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
            "name":"output",
            "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/output/",
            "builds":[ 

            ]
        },
        { 
            "_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
            "name":"pipeline_test",
            "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/",
            "builds":[ 
                { 
                    "_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
                    "duration":9274,
                    "number":85,
                    "result":"SUCCESS",
                    "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/85/"
                },
                { 
                    "_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
                    "duration":4251,
                    "number":84,
                    "result":"SUCCESS",
                    "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/84/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From the above JSON i want to fetch jobs name value and builds result  value . I am new to python any help will be appreciated .
Till now i have tried

```
main_data = data['jobs]
json_normalize(main_data,['builds'],
                    record_prefix='jobs_', errors='ignore')
```

which gives information only build key values and not the name of job .
Can anyone help ?

**Expected Output**:

[image: image for expected output]

Comment: Can you please post expected output from JSON? And how that output you want into CSV? It would help us to resolve faster.

Comment: i have uploaded a image of expected output

Comment: But builds is list and contains multiple result values, which value should be considered for csv?

Comment: @AkashPagar only the first result value has to be considered,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering only first build result value you can need to be in csv column you can achieve this using pandas.

```py
data = {
    "class": "hudson.model.Hudson",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
            "name": "git_checkout",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/git_checkout/",
            "builds": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
                    "duration": 1201,
                    "number": 6,
                    "result": "FAILURE",
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/git_checkout/6/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
            "name": "output",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/output/",
            "builds": []
        },
        {
            "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
            "name": "pipeline_test",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/",
            "builds": [
                {
                    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
                    "duration": 9274,
                    "number": 85,
                    "result": "SUCCESS",
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/85/"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
                    "duration": 4251,
                    "number": 84,
                    "result": "SUCCESS",
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline_test/84/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

main_data = data.get('jobs')
res = {'name':[], 'result':[]}
for name_dict in main_data:
    res['name'].append(name_dict.get('name','NA'))
    resultval = name_dict['builds'][0].get('result') if len(name_dict['builds'])>0 else 'NA'
    res['result'].append(resultval)
print(res)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.to_csv("/home/file_timer/jobs.csv", index=False)
```

Check the csv file output

```
name,result
git_checkout,FAILURE
output,NA
pipeline_test,SUCCESS
```

If 'NA' result want to skip then

```py
main_data = data.get('jobs')
res = {'name':[], 'result':[]}
for name_dict in main_data:
    if len(name_dict['builds'])==0:
        continue
    res['name'].append(name_dict.get('name', 'NA'))
    resultval = name_dict['builds'][0].get('result')
    res['result'].append(resultval)
print(res)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.to_csv("/home/akash.pagar/shell_learning/file_timer/jobs.csv", index=False)
```

Output will bw like

```
name,result
git_checkout,FAILURE
pipeline_test,SUCCESS
```

Comment: If you want don't want rows with No output i.e ```len(builds)==0``` just insert this snippet in for loop ```if len(name_dict['builds'])==0:
        continue
    res['name'].append(name_dict.get('name', 'NA'))
    resultval = name_dict['builds'][0].get('result')
    res['result'].append(resultval)```

Comment: thanks akash its working as i expected thanks a lot...also can you please give the last solution just for reference if we need result of multpile builds if needed .

Comment: hi akash  i am getting error     if len(name_dict['builds'])==0:
KeyError: 'builds'   dont know why can you help please . i have tried for a larger json this time

Comment: try using ```len(name_dict.get('builds', []))==0```. For larger jsons try to use ```.get()`` method which will avoid the ```KeyError``

Answer (score 0):

Simply with build number,

```
for job in data.get('jobs'):
    for build in job.get('builds'):
        print(job.get('name'), build.get('number'), build.get('result'))
```

gives the result

```
git_checkout 6 FAILURE
pipeline_test 85 SUCCESS
pipeline_test 84 SUCCESS
```

---

If you want to get the result of latest build, and pretty sure about the build number always in decending order,

```
for job in data.get('jobs'):
    if job.get('builds'):
        print(job.get('name'), job.get('builds')[0].get('result'))
```

and if you are not sure the order,

```
for job in data.get('jobs'):
    if job.get('builds'):
        print(job.get('name'), sorted(job.get('builds'), key=lambda k: k.get('number'))[-1].get('result'))
```

then the result will be:

```
git_checkout FAILURE
pipeline_test SUCCESS
```

Comment: thanks lamanus but what if i just want latest build result only ? and also in csv file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming last build is the last element of its list and you don't care about jobs with no builds, this does:

```
import pandas as pd

#data = ... #same format as in the question

z = [(job["name"], job["builds"][-1]["result"]) for job in data["jobs"] if len(job["builds"])]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=z, columns=["name", "result"])

#df.to_csv #TODO
```

Also we don't necessarily need pandas to create the csv file.

You could do:

```
import csv

#z = ... #see previous code block

with open("f.csv", 'w') as fp:
    csv.writer(fp).writerows([("name", "result")] + z)
```